# make one cell value 0 if other cell value > 0 using excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
A   B
0   1
2   0
3   0
0   4
5   0
```

if i write something on Cell.(A1)= 0 it make  cell(B1) =0 automatically.
if i write something on Cell.(B1)= 0 it make  cell(A1) =0 automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose that you want base values in B column on values on A value.

Then your code should look like this:

```
Sub fillValues()
Dim i, k As Integer
k = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count     'determine last row
For i = 1 To k
    If Cells(i, 1).Value > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i am new in VBA (xls) 
how i would apply this code?

Comment: Just open Visual Basic window in Excel, past it, then you should be able to run it as a macro.

Comment: Thank you for your quick support

Answer (score 1):

If youwant the values to auto chenge once you enter a value of `0` anywhere in columns A:B, then you need to have your code in `Worksheet_Change` event.

Note: not sure I underatand if you want to mekt the other cell `0` when you change one of the cells to `0` or from `0`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A:B")) Is Nothing Then ' check if a cell in Columns A:B is changed
    If Target.Value = 0 Then '<-- if the value changed is 0
    ' option 2 to your post
    'If Target.Value > 0 Then '<-- if the value changed is > 0
        Select Case Target.Column '<-- check which column modifed, A or B
            Case 1
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = 0
            Case 2
                Target.Offset(, -1).Value = 0
        End Select            
    End If    
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick support